# Disable PhpStorm's alignment on js function params destructuring

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, eslint, reformatting

When I write my code like this:

[image: Good]

I ask PhpStorm to reformat my code, and it does like this:

[image: Bad]

Ugly... How can I tell PhpStorm to not align params like this and leave it as it is?

Code sample:

```
export const scanIntervals = ({
    intervals,
    duration,
    start = 0,
    end = 1440,
    rounding = 10,
}) => intervals.some((interval) => {
    console.log('Hello World');
})
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Is that TypeScript or JavaScript? (sorry, not JS person myself). It should be at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | [LANGUAGE] | Wrapping and Braces` -- most likely one of the `Align when multiline` options. Would be good if you could provide an actual code sample as a text (so it can be copy-pasted into preview area and checked with few options)

Comment: @LazyOne Didnt find anything associated with it. Long searched for the necessary option but without any success. JavaScript ES6

Comment: I personally would not be able to provide any help without some code sample that I can copy-paste .. as I simply do not know JavaScript at this level so cannot make my own (rather basic jQuery and alike usage). In such conditions I may only suggest to copy-paste your code there yourself and try checking/unchecking different options (paste again after resetting that option back). Sorry about that. Maybe somebody else knows exact option.

Comment: @LazyOne done..

Comment: Thanks. Please post your current Code Style for JavaScript (that `Wrapping and Braces` tab) -- I want to compare it to mine (just export it and share somehow). In my tests `Function declaration parameters | Align when multiline` does trigger such big indent.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks a lot! It does exactly what I need! You can make a answer from your comment.
I didn't see this option presumably because I'm from Russia. Sorry for my stupid question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156294/discussion-between---and-lazyone).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Wrapping and Braces`
3. `Function declaration parameters --> Align when multiline`

Accordingly to my tests using your code sample it's the option that is responsible for such behaviour. Please uncheck it.